# textarea innerHTML / html() не работает

Tags: javascript, html, entity

По клику на ячейке таблицы, с помощью js в ячейку добавляется код галочки

```
$(this).css('text-align','center').html('&#10003;');
```

но некоторые галочки не отображаются. Почему?
т.е. в каждой ячейке находится `textarea`, и внутрь `textarea` добавляется код галочки.
пример ячейки:

```
<td>
<label for="cell-B5"><span class="screen-reader-text">Колонка 2, Строка 5</span></label>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qftgcw9/1/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0qftgcw9/1/

Comment: добавил пример в jsfiddle, там если удалить существующие галочки, и поставить новые, то некоторых не видно

Comment: Давайте начнем с того нужен ли вам в ячейках textarea. Не вижу логики. Если есть поле для ввода, значит это нужно обрабатывать, тогда зачем галочки?. Потом: ваш код написан коряво. Если кликнуть в области td но мимо textarea - ваш textarea пропадет. Опишите, пожалуйста, логику сего кода

Comment: @Александр Маринов, это вордпресс плагин, textarea там нужен, без него никак в этом плагине, на textarea есть обработчик. А мой код, это я привёл пример ячейки из этого плагина, поэтому мой js этот как пример, но в jsfiddle можно увидеть эту проблему с неотображением галочки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось... менять `.html()` элемента textarea можно только до тех пор, пока кто-то вручную или скриптом не поменял его значение `.val()`. Поэтому, всегда добавлять html() в textarea невозможно, нужно организовать всё через val()

*JS-аналоги: `.innerHTML = '✓';` и `.value = '✓';`

**Сам HTML-то меняется. Визуального отображения нет.

***Там вы лишний раз при каждом клике делали text-align: center... легче это один раз задать в CSS и забыть о нем.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/ur67mwba/)

```js
$('td').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('textarea').val('✓');
});

$('#ok').on('click', function(){
  $('textarea').val('');
});
```

```css
textarea {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
    <td>
<textarea name="table[data][4][1]" id="cell-B5" rows="1" style="text-align: center;">✓</textarea>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows=""></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows=""></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows=""></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</table>


<button id="ok">Убрать всё</button>
```